# Reactjs Howto Blur Background image on scroll?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, blur, styled-components

I'm new to reactjs and I would like understand how to reproduce this jquery example in Reactjs styled-components : Blurring background image on event "Scroll"
https://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMoon/8jhw2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
            opacityVal = (s / 200);

        $('.blurred-image').css('opacity', opacityVal);
    });
});
```

```
.img-src { 
    position: absolute;
    background:url(http://bromleydemo.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/blossom.jpg?w=600) center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

as you've seen the background url is set into css prop
I've tried something in reactjs but each time I scroll, the image background is reloaded. 
Can somebody help me ?

ps : If the solution can be implemented with styled-components it will be awesome

ps2 : this is another page of the effect i'm trying to implement 
https://codepen.io/zrichard/pen/wEFBd

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind an event listener to the window using [the useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

[Live sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-sea-txmfr).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
import { hydrate, render } from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = () => setOpacity(window.scrollY / 200);

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return function cleanup() {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <BlurredImageContainer>
        <ImgSrc />
        <ImgSrc blurred opacity={opacity} />
      </BlurredImageContainer>
      <Content>
        <Avatar src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000748837969/bd8e553e5cae83ef488c6b15166bdd55.png" />
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
      </Content>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const BlurredImageContainer = styled.div`
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
`;

const ImgSrc = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  background: url("http://bromleydemo.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/blossom.jpg?w=600") center center;
  background-size: cover;
  top: -10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: -10%;
  right: 10%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;

  ${props => props.blurred && css`
    opacity: ${props.opacity};
    filter: blur(20px) brightness(0.7);
  `};
`;

const Content = styled.div`
  padding: 150px 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
`;

const Avatar = styled.div`
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
`;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
if (rootElement.hasChildNodes()) {
  hydrate(<App />, rootElement);
} else {
  render(<App />, rootElement);
}
```

Comment: Hi Cody,
many thanks for your reply, it allow me to go deeper in ReactJS exploring Hooks. I find one problem which I explain in the next comment and I suggest a solution. Let me know your point of vue.

Answer (score 3):

Your sample code is really good except one thing which is very difficult to implement properly with all these frameworks : SCROLLING.

If you open a debug Console, you'll see this kind of warning message (when you scroll up and down, the display will be "blank" if you scroll quickly)

> Over 200 classes were generated for component bg-opacity-v2__ImgSrc. 
>   Consider using the attrs method, together with a style object for frequently changed styles.

```
Example:
  const Component = styled.div.attrs({
    style: ({ background }) => ({
      background,
    }),
  })`width: 100%;`

  <Component />
```

I find a solution using component ".attrs" method.

```
const ImgSrc = styled.div.attrs(props => ({
  style: {
    opacity: `${props.opacity}`,
    filter: "blur(" + `${props.filter}` + "px) brightness(0.7)",
  },
}))`
  position: absolute;
  background: url("http://bromleydemo.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/blossom.jpg?w=600")
    center center;
  background-size: cover;
  top: -10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: -10%;
  right: 10%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
`
```

Here is a new version of your code. I deleted the first tag , modify the opacity computation but it's a detail. 
I don't really understand why I have to extract the opacity computation from the "useEffect" method, but it works fine like that.

```
const onScroll = () => {
    setOpacity(scrollOpacity())
    setFilter(scrollFilter())
}
```

This new version works well.

[Live Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-turing-jivgb)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
import { hydrate, render } from "react-dom";

function scrollOpacity() {
  const winScroll =
    document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  const height =
    document.documentElement.scrollHeight -
    document.documentElement.clientHeight;

  const scrolled = winScroll / height;
  const newOpacity = 1 + scrolled * 2;
  return newOpacity;
}

function scrollFilter() {
  const winScroll =
    document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  const newFilter = 0 + winScroll / 100;
  return newFilter;
}

function App() {
  const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(1);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = () => {
      setOpacity(scrollOpacity());
      setFilter(scrollFilter());
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return function cleanup() {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <BlurredImageContainer>
        <ImgSrc opacity={opacity} filter={filter} />
      </BlurredImageContainer>
      <Content>
        <Avatar src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000748837969/bd8e553e5cae83ef488c6b15166bdd55.png" />
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
        <p>This is some test content</p>
      </Content>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const BlurredImageContainer = styled.div`
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
`;

const ImgSrc = styled.div.attrs(props => ({
  style: {
    opacity: `${props.opacity}`,
    filter: "blur(" + `${props.filter}` + "px) brightness(0.7)"
  }
}))`
  position: absolute;
  background: url("http://bromleydemo.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/blossom.jpg?w=600")
    center center;
  background-size: cover;
  top: -10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: -10%;
  right: 10%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
`;

const Content = styled.div`
  padding: 150px 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
`;

const Avatar = styled.div`
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
`;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
if (rootElement.hasChildNodes()) {
  hydrate(<App />, rootElement);
} else {
  render(<App />, rootElement);
}
```

If anybody have an optimization or better way to do this, your are welcomed.