# I need to create a Blur on scroll component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Would anyone be able to help me with a Blur on scroll component in React? I just need something simple. That when you scroll down the page it just transitions into the blur effect. I've been struggling with this for a while now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to blur the image combined with a scroll effect function in javascript.
Example :

```
<style>
img {
  filter: blur(3px) brightness(0.7);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you GrimReaper, Would it at all be possible to show me a little more in depth as to how it would tie into react? I've just started React so Im struggling to place regular js code into it. I would imagine that i need to use state as the value changes. But that's all i've got.

Comment: I can't understand your use case so it's better for you to learn how to do it yourself. So please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972547/reactjs-howto-blur-background-image-on-scroll